# Understanding cross-threading Controls access C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having some trouble accessing the UI from an another thread.
I understand the basics on cross-threading limitations, but I can't seem to write the code that will work. More specifically, I can't access the ListView from a static method (thread).

I'm trying to make it work with `backgroundWorker`.

Here's my code:

```
private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 20;
    var tasks = new List<Task<int>>();

    foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
    {
        string currentUrl = item.SubItems[1].Text;
        int i = item.Index;
        tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { return GetWebResponse(currentUrl, i); }));
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}

private static int GetWebResponse(string url, int itemIndex)
{
    int statusCode = 0;
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);           

    Task<HttpWebResponse> responseTask = Task.Factory.FromAsync<HttpWebResponse>(httpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse, asyncResult => (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult), null);

    backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker_DoWork);
    backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged);
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();


    return statusCode;
}

private void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    listView1.Items[0].ImageKey = "green";
}

private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (!e.Cancel)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(0);
    }
}
```

This code doesn't work because `backgroundWorker_DoWork` and `backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged` are **not** `static`, but if I make them static then I can't access `listView1`

EDIT: Got it working. Code below for review

```
public delegate void delUpdateListView(int itemIndex, int statusCode);

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 20;
    var tasks = new List<Task<int>>();

    foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
    {
        string currentUrl = item.SubItems[1].Text;
        int i = item.Index;
        tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            //return GetWebResponse(currentUrl, i);

            int statusCode = 0;
            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(currentUrl);

            Task<HttpWebResponse> responseTask = Task.Factory.FromAsync<HttpWebResponse>(httpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse, asyncResult => (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult), null);
            statusCode = (int)responseTask.Result.StatusCode;

            object[] invParams = new object[2];
            invParams[0] = i;
            invParams[1] = statusCode;

            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                BeginInvoke(new delUpdateListView(UpdateListView), invParams);
            }
            else
            {
                Invoke(new delUpdateListView(UpdateListView), invParams);
            }


            return statusCode;

        }));
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}

public void UpdateListView(int itemIndex, int statusCode) {
    listView1.Items[itemIndex].ImageKey = "green";
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several problems here:

1) I don't see why `GetWebResponse` needs to be `static`. The easiest solution would be to make it an instance method.

2) Why are you using the background worker anyway?

3) It doesn't make much sense to use `Task`s and then wait for them to finish right after you spawn them. This blocks your application where it should be responsive.

As for 3): To keep the UI responsive and updatable, disable everything the user may not click before spawning the tasks, add a continuation action to each task that re-enables the UI components. The task may update the list using the usual `Invoke` calls.

Comment: Thanks. That helped me getting it working. Could you please check my Edit to see if it follows the best practices. I've added the Invoke calls you mentioned

Comment: Looks better :-) You're using an `Invoke` call in any case in your code. The code should be like `if (InvokeRequired) DoStuffWithInvoke; else DoStuffDirectlyWithoutInvoke;`. And you can use an anonymous delegate like `Invoke((Action)delegate() { UpdateListView(i, statusCode); });` and don't need a delegate type then.